# Как использовать password_hash()?

Tags: php, password-hash

Кто пользуется уже этой функцией, подскажите, как правильно организовать обработку паролей с ее помощью чтобы не запороть авторизацию по паролю и защитить хеш в базе?

прим.
какой столбец использовать в базе MySQL
какой длины должен быть столбец
пример обращения с функцией

Answer (score 1):

допустим при регистрации сервер получает пароль далее обрабатывает его с помощью аля

```
$finite_password password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

далее записываешь $finite_password в базу (поле можешь сделать типа varchar(255), так рекомендовано на оф сайте php).

Правка(спасибо @Мелкий).
При авторизации

```
password_verify ($(пароль полученный от пользователя), $(хешированный пароль из базы))
```

password_verify возвращает TRUE или FALSE, если значение TRUE то авторизируешь, а если FALSE то ошибку, все готово.
Надеюсь я правильно понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: "производишь тот же процесс с полученным паролем" - не тот же. Далеко не тот же. password_hash всегда генерирует новый хэш. Для проверки, подходит ли переданный пароль к имеющемуся хэшу, сделана функция password_verify

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо что поправил меня

Answer (score -1):

> какой столбец использовать в базе MySQL

любой подходящий. например, `text`.

> какой длины должен быть столбец

например, дефолтной.

> пример обращения с функцией

например, со [страницы документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php):

```
$ php -r 'echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";'
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

Comment: Да, мануал читается первым делом. Примеры смотрел. Как быть с алгоритмами, что выбрать?  К примеру, PASSWORD_BCRYPT с какими параметрами лучше использовать или все же использовать PASSWORD_DEFAULT и не заморачиваться?

Comment: если перед вами встаёт вопрос «что лучше?», то выбор умолчального варианта, я думаю, вас удовлетворит. а вот когда (если) он перестанет удовлетворять, то вы к тому моменту, вероятно, уже будете знать, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Довольно странно выбирать "что лучше" из одного варианта =) На данный момент DEFAULT указывает на BCRYPT